# C# WPF changing opacity from canvas in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Canvas in a Grid and the Grid has a opacity of 0.5 but the Canvas in the Grid has a opacity of 1 and its not works both modules have 0.5 opacity. In the Canvas is a Rectangle which should also have an opacity of 1.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
    
    <Grid
        x:Name="grid"
        MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"
        MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp"
        MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove"
        Background="Black"      
        Opacity="0.5">
        
        <Canvas Opacity="1">
            <Rectangle
                x:Name="selectionBox"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                Stroke="White"
                StrokeThickness="1"  
                Opacity="1"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is so far my Code, the opacity in Grid works, but when it comes to Canvas it wont works. The opacity from Canvas/Rectangle stays at 0.5 as with Grid.

I would appreciate any help or suggestion

Comment: I don't follow what the issue is. I'm confused by your explanation.

Comment: Oh sorry! I am not a native english speaker. I have a Fullscreen Application. I want the background transparent but the Rectangle and what is inside should not be transparent. Like a Screenshot tool.

Comment: Rather than set opacity on the grid at all. Have you tried a transparent colour? Using #argb rather than a named colour.

Comment: Yes I've tested it. actually get the same result. Ashley answer works until it comes to the content from the rectangle. I want the content in full transparent, but the content has the black opacity .5 background from the grid before. currently testing some border stuff but don't really get any further.

Comment: Setting the background to a transparent brush simply cannot lead to inheriting that into that panel's content. So i doubt you did what i suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Any child elements in your grid will be rendered with the opacity of the parent I believe. One way around it is to create a Grid for your black background with opacity of 0.5 and then add the Canvas on top. Put both these inside another grid and set them to the same row making sure the Canvas is the last element.

Hope this is what you needed.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <Grid
            x:Name="grid"
            Grid.Row="0"
            MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"
            MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp"
            MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove"
            Background="Black"      
            Opacity="0.5">
        </Grid>

        <Canvas Grid.Row="0">
            <Rectangle
                x:Name="selectionBox"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                Stroke="White"
                StrokeThickness="1"  
                Opacity="1"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Ah OK, this works much better. The Stroke has no opacity now, this is perfect, but inside of the Rectangle its still opacity 0.5. Fill="Transparent" seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set an opacity and a background (if there are any) for your grid separately:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">

<Grid
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.1"/>
    </Grid.Background>

    x:Name="grid"
    MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"
    MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp"
    MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove"
    Background="Black"      
    Opacity="0.5">
    
    <Canvas Opacity="1">
        <Rectangle
            x:Name="selectionBox"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            Stroke="White"
            StrokeThickness="1"  
            Opacity="1"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

In my case, it works for canvas.